# nginx doesn't display favicon

Tags: nginx, favicon

So i decided to play around with nginx and i managed to run correctly both htm and php files ( php-fpm ) but there is a problem: it does not display the favicon, nor in the root neither in the other directories.

nginx.conf:

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  2;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
#error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log  notice;
#error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log  info;

pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  512;
}


http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    #keepalive_timeout  0;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    server {
        listen       8000;
        server_name  www.domain.com domain.com;
        autoindex off;
        root /var/www/html;

        #access_log  /var/log/nginx/host.access.log  main;

        location / {
            index index.html index.htm;
        }

        # redirect server error pages to the static page /40x.html
        #
        error_page  404              /notfound.htm;
        #location = /notfound.html {
        #    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        #}

        # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
        #
        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        #location = /50x.html {
        #    #root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        #}

        #pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
        #
        location ~ \.php$ {
            fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
            fastcgi_index  index.php;
            fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
            include /etc/nginx/fastcgi.conf;
        }

        # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
        # concurs with nginx's one
        #
        location ~ /\.ht {
            deny  all;
        }
    }

    # Load config files from the /etc/nginx/conf.d directory
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

}
```

mime.types:

```
types {
    text/html                             html htm shtml;
    text/css                              css;
    text/xml                              xml;
    image/gif                             gif;
    image/jpeg                            jpeg jpg;
    application/x-javascript              js;
    application/atom+xml                  atom;
    application/rss+xml                   rss;

    text/mathml                           mml;
    text/plain                            txt;
    text/vnd.sun.j2me.app-descriptor      jad;
    text/vnd.wap.wml                      wml;
    text/x-component                      htc;

    image/png                             png;
    image/tiff                            tif tiff;
    image/vnd.wap.wbmp                    wbmp;
    image/x-icon                          ico;
    image/x-jng                           jng;
    image/x-ms-bmp                        bmp;
    image/svg+xml                         svg svgz;
    image/webp                            webp;

    application/java-archive              jar war ear;
    application/mac-binhex40              hqx;
    application/msword                    doc;
    application/pdf                       pdf;
    application/postscript                ps eps ai;
    application/rtf                       rtf;
    application/vnd.ms-excel              xls;
    application/vnd.ms-powerpoint         ppt;
    application/vnd.wap.wmlc              wmlc;
    application/vnd.google-earth.kml+xml  kml;
    application/vnd.google-earth.kmz      kmz;
    application/x-7z-compressed           7z;
    application/x-cocoa                   cco;
    application/x-java-archive-diff       jardiff;
    application/x-java-jnlp-file          jnlp;
    application/x-makeself                run;
    application/x-perl                    pl pm;
    application/x-pilot                   prc pdb;
    application/x-rar-compressed          rar;
    application/x-redhat-package-manager  rpm;
    application/x-sea                     sea;
    application/x-shockwave-flash         swf;
    application/x-stuffit                 sit;
    application/x-tcl                     tcl tk;
    application/x-x509-ca-cert            der pem crt;
    application/x-xpinstall               xpi;
    application/xhtml+xml                 xhtml;
    application/zip                       zip;

    application/octet-stream              bin exe dll;
    application/octet-stream              deb;
    application/octet-stream              dmg;
    application/octet-stream              eot;
    application/octet-stream              iso img;
    application/octet-stream              msi msp msm;

    audio/midi                            mid midi kar;
    audio/mpeg                            mp3;
    audio/ogg                             ogg;
    audio/x-m4a                           m4a;
    audio/x-realaudio                     ra;

    video/3gpp                            3gpp 3gp;
    video/mp4                             mp4;
    video/mpeg                            mpeg mpg;
    video/quicktime                       mov;
    video/webm                            webm;
    video/x-flv                           flv;
    video/x-m4v                           m4v;
    video/x-mng                           mng;
    video/x-ms-asf                        asx asf;
    video/x-ms-wmv                        wmv;
    video/x-msvideo                       avi;
}
```

am i doing something wrong ? i don't see any errors in the nginx error log. the favicon gets displayed correctly through apache.

Comment: If you look at the HTTP response is the image returned from the server or does it return a 404?

Comment: firefox's web console at Net section does not display any info on the favicon either with apache or nginx

Comment: check the server logs not firefox's console and look for the HTTP response for facicon is it 200 or 404 like Brent said?

Comment: when i try to directly hit the favicon file, i can see it in the browser and the reponse is 200. Otherwise, when i visit a normal html file, there is nothing in the logs concerning the favicon.ico

Comment: Are you sure you're HTML references the favicon file in the head section? I know that sounds stupid but it sounds like the file isn't calling for it to load.

Comment: @BrentPabst yes I do, the favicon gets displayed normally by apache ( they share the same folder with nginx ). here is the reference in index.htm <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/favicon.ico"/>

Comment: OK so pull up either the server's logs or use Fiddler, what is the response code returned when you try to open the page with the favicon link?  200, 404, ?

Comment: i was about to do just that, when i noticed that today it does display the favicon. this is weird.